# Get this weekend in php?

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to get this weekend in php.

I get the current date by code :

```
$start_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
```

How I can get the current weekend depend on the curent date? Thank you!

Comment: dupe?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349820/get-weekend-dates-in-php/3349897#3349897

Comment: please define "current weekend". Friday? Saturday? Sunday? All of them? If you want Friday and we are on Sunday, should it return next friday or previous? Please be more specific.

Comment: what does "this weekend" mean? the number of the week? date of the [next / last / nearest] [friday / saturday / sunday]?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

PHP [strtotime](http://fr.php.net/strtotime) function is magic, most of people don't know but you can do a lot of things with this function.

```
$start_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('next Saturday'));
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime)

```
$sat = strtotime('saturday');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$start_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('Saturday'));
```

Answer (score 1):

My definition of "weekend" is next Friday, end of office hours up to end of Sunday.
In PHP, this would be

```
$weekend = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('next Friday 18:00'),
    DateInterval::createFromDateString('+1 hour'),
    new DateTime('next Friday +2 day 23:59'));

foreach($weekend as $hours) {
    echo $hours->format( "l Y-m-d H:i:s\n" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$time = mktime();
$found = false;
while(!$found) {
    $d = date('N', $time);
    if($d == 6 || $d == 7) {
        $found = true;
        $weekend = date('d/m/Y G:i:s', $time);
    }
    $time += 86400;
}
echo("Weekend begins on: $weekend");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**First weekend calculation**

```
if(date('w')==6){// Today is Saturday | Bugün Cumartesi ise
  $wknd=date("Y-md-").'-'.date("Y-m-d", strtotime('next Sunday'));
}if(date('w')==0){// Today is Sunday | Bugün Pazar ise
  $wknd=date("Y-m-d");
}else{ // On weekdays | Hafta içi ise
 $wknd=date("Y-m-d", strtotime('next Saturday')).'-'.date("Ymd", strtotime('next Sunday'));
}
echo $wknd;
```