# How to get weekend day in this week by any given date?

Tags: php

for example, get the weekend of today.

Comment: You should give more details - do you want the weekend which falls *after* the given date, or *before* the given date? How should it behave when given a Sunday?

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/183442-weekend-date-given-date This will help you in going ahead

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I never could even imagine you even enter such questions :-)

Comment: A non-programming answer would be to ask this guy - http://www.google.com/m/url?client=safari&ei=xAcsTbDkA5edtwfknL-TAQ&hl=en&oe=UTF-8&q=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v%3DM4vqr3_ROIk&ved=0CBkQtwIwAg&usg=AFQjCNEyHqLW19tE4Ii0tvMv1eA9j5VM_g (professor at Harvey Mudd College)

Comment: @Jon Skeet I'm not familiar with english. in my native language, this always means 'after'

Comment: @lovespring: Okay, so presumably if you were given a Sunday you'd want the *next* Saturday and Sunday? What about if you were given a Saturday? It really helps to be precise when asking questions like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get this weekend in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243760/get-this-weekend-in-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get weekend dates in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349820/get-weekend-dates-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get this weekend in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243760/get-this-weekend-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for e.g. the next or previous saturday (or any other weekday for that matter) [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) is your friend.

```
$prev = strtotime('-1 saturday');    
$next = strtotime('saturday');

var_dump($prev, $next);
```

It's worth noting that `strtotime` is quite an expensive function, so multiple calculations will noticiably add to your execution time. A good compromise is using it to get a starting point and using the other [date functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) to derive further dates.

Answer (score 3):

This is brilliantly easy in PHP:

```
<?php

echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'next Saturday' ) );

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
get the current date.
get the current day of week. (0=monday, 6 = sunday)
days2weekend = 5 - current day of week 
dateadd(currentdate, days, days2weekend)
```

Comment: Hmm, actually depends on what you call "week-end" (the end of the week "weekend" is sunday, the start of "week-end" is saturday), and when your week actually ends - and then there are those culture where the first working day in "the week" is sunday. There is actually no easy answer to this question, because we don't know for which culture, and not what is meant by "weekend" either...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit a hard to follow, but do you mean "the next weekend" from a certain date?

You could get the the weekday number, and then see how much to add for saturday and sundag? That would look like:

```
<?php   
    $dayNR = date('N');         //monday = 1, tuesday = 2, etc.
    $satDiff = 6-$dayNR;        //for monday we need to add 5 days -> 6 - 1
    $sunDiff = $satDiff+1;      //sunday is one day more
    $satDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(" +".$satDiff." days"));
    $sunDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(" +".$sunDiff." days"));

    echo $satDate."\n";
    echo $sunDate."\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the built-in PHP function strtotime should work for you. Eg:

```
strtotime('next saturday')
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php