# pre select dates based on dropdown selection in bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

Anyone know, how I can achieve below:

1. If someone select the option "For weekend only" then all the weekend dates will be selected from the current month to the next month's specified date.
2. if someone select the option "For weekday only" then all the weekday dates will be selected from the current month to the next month's specified date.
3. if someone select the option "For Friday only" then all the Friday dates will be selected from the current month to the next month's specified date.

Something like above:
[image]

Anyone have any idea where I can start this with??

```
$('#dt_1').datepicker({
        rtl: KTUtil.isRTL(),
        todayHighlight: true,
        templates: arrows,
        startDate: date, //disable all old dates
        setDate: date, //tomorrow's date allowed
        multidate: true,
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution to achieve this with the help of another post of stackoverflow:
[get weekend using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349820/get-weekend-dates-in-php)

PHP code:

```
//weekend.....
$now = strtotime("now");
$end_date = strtotime("+3 weeks");
$weekend_array = array();
while (date("d-m-Y", $now) != date("d-m-Y", $end_date)) {
    $day_index = date("w", $now);
    if ($day_index == 0 || $day_index == 6) {  
        // Print or store the weekends here.  
        //echo "<br>".$day_index."- Date: ".date("d-m-Y", $now);
        $weekend_array[] = date("d-m-Y", $now);
    }
    $now = strtotime(date("d-m-Y", $now) . "+1 day");
}

//friday only....               
$now = strtotime("now");
$end_date = strtotime("+3 weeks");
$friday_array = array();
while (date("d-m-Y", $now) != date("d-m-Y", $end_date)) {
    $day_index = date("w", $now);
    if ($day_index == 5) {  
        // Print or store the weekends here.  
        //echo "<br>".$day_index."- Date: ".date("d-m-Y", $now);
        $friday_array[] = date("d-m-Y", $now);
    }
    $now = strtotime(date("d-m-Y", $now) . "+1 day");
}

//weekdays......                  
$now = strtotime("now");
$end_date = strtotime("+3 weeks");
$weekday_array = array();
while (date("d-m-Y", $now) != date("d-m-Y", $end_date)) {
    $day_index = date("w", $now);
    if ($day_index >= 1 && $day_index <= 5) {  
        // Print or store the weekends here.  
        //echo "<br>".$day_index."- Date: ".date("d-m-Y", $now);
        $weekday_array[] = date("d-m-Y", $now);
    }
    $now = strtotime(date("d-m-Y", $now) . "+1 day");
}
```

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {

$("#sel_dropdown").change(function() {
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
        var v = $(this).val();
        if(v == 1) {
            //weekend only....
            $('#dt_1').datepicker('setDates',[<?php 
                $i=0;   
                for($i=0;$i<=count($weekend_array);$i++) {
                    echo "'".$weekend_array[$i]."',";
                }
            ?>]);
        }
        if(v == 2) {
            //Friday only.....
            $('#dt_1').datepicker('setDates',[<?php 
                $i=0;   
                for($i=0;$i<=count($friday_array);$i++) {
                    echo "'".$friday_array[$i]."',";
                }
            ?>]);
        }
        if(v == 3) {
            //Weekdays only....
            $('#dt_1').datepicker('setDates',[<?php 
                $i=0;   
                for($i=0;$i<=count($weekday_array);$i++) {
                    echo "'".$weekday_array[$i]."',";
                }
            ?>]);
        }
        if(v == 4) {
            //custom option....
            $('#dt_1').data('datepicker').setDate(null); 
        }
    });

});

});
</script>
```

Hopefully, this will useful for anyone looking for this type of solution.